# can anyone check and fix my vector problem

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

This is the code to print the pointer vector in decreasing order. In this code the size function of the vector is not working. The input is `long long int` so i had taken a `long long int` pointer.

```
class Number{
  long long int *num;
  public:
  Number(long long int t);
  void largestNumber();
};

//Complete this function below
Number :: Number(long long int t){
  //Complete this function
  vector <long long int> a; 
  while(t)
  {
      a.push_back(t%10);
      t=t/10;
  }
  num=a.data();
}

void Number :: largestNumber(){
  //Complete this function
    for(long long int i=0;i<num->end();i++)
    {
        for(long long int j=1;j<num.size();j++)
        {
            if(num[i]<num[j])
            {
                int temp=num[i];
                num[i]=num[j];
                num[j]=temp;
            }

        }
        cout<<num[i];
    }
}


int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
    long long int num;
    cin>>num;
    Number obj(num);
    obj.largestNumber();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of "not working" ? Do you get a compiler error? Wrong output? whatever it is please include it in the question

Comment: "the pointer vector" - pointers and vectors are different things. The pointer `long long int *num` doesn't have the methods `num->end()` and `num.size()`.

Comment: This code does not compile. Fixing the compiler errors will help you zero in on the actual problem.

Comment: Also `num=a.data();` turns `num` into a dangling pointer (after the function is finished)

Comment: In the `Number` constructor, you are creating a local vector, pointing the `num` member to its internal data, and then letting it go out of scope, destroying it and leaving `num` as a dangling pointer so it is invalid for use in `largestNumber()`

Comment: `num` is not `vector` so you cannot call `size()`

Answer (score 3):

This code is incorrect:

```
//Complete this function below
Number :: Number(long long int t){
    //Complete this function
    vector <long long int> a; 
    while(t)
    {
        a.push_back(t%10);
        t=t/10;
    }
    num=a.data();
}
```

The vector `a` only exists in the constructor. When the constructor exits, `a` is destroyed. But you have saved a pointer to the vectors data in `num`, so you end up with an invalid pointer.

Here's the correct code. As usual, the answer is **don't use pointers**.

```
class Number
{
    std::vector<long long int> num; // don't use pointers
public:
    Number(long long int t);
    void largestNumber();
};

Number::Number(long long int t)
{
    while (t)
    {
        num.push_back(t%10);
        t = t/10;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also include a working `largestNumber()` showing the proper use of `num`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Generally I like to leave something for the OP to do. Maybe they can figure it out.

Comment: in the above solution you have corrected the num pointer to vector. but what if i want the num to be pointer. then how could i store the data in it. if dynamically creating an array and the storing the data. then in the largestNumber() func how could i know the size of the array.

Comment: @PriyanshuSuman There is no way to know the size of a dynamically allocated array. What you have to do is store the size of the array in a separate variable (which is all that std::vector is doing).

Comment: but it is a hacker rank question i cannot chnge the given sintex

Comment: as you suggested i can store the size in another var then how can i access in other function

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/cpluspractice/challenges/andrew-and-pointers

Comment: You write a class that has the pointer and the size in the same object. Then all the methods of that object (like largestNumber) get access both the pointer and its size.

Comment: plz check the question

Comment: I cannot change the class of the question

Comment: @PriyanshuSuman I understand. Why do you need to allocate any memory at all? Why not just store the number and then do **all** the work in largestNumber?

Comment: @PriyanshuSuman I hope you are joking, but I think you probably aren't.

Comment: as i am understanding you are doing all the stuff in a single function

Comment: That is what I said. You split the work between the constructor and `largestNumber`. That's just making it difficult.

Comment: plz dont take me wrong im not trying to solve the question with the help of you and the submit it

Comment: check i had solved it. but as per the question i was thinking how to do the question with the help of both the functions